# JPA 2.1 entity, Why I always got the entity self instead of the entity's primary key?

Tags: entity-framework, jpa, entity, primary-key

This is a deeper digger from my previous question.

I had a NetBeans generated entity classes from by Postgresql server. The source code is:

```
package com.longz.ozssc.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by cidylong on 12/01/2015.
*/
@Entity
@Table(name = "file", schema = "public", catalog = "ozssc")
public class FileEntity {
    private String fileId;
    private String referId;
    private String fileName;
    private String fileType;
    private byte[] fileData;
    private Time createdDatatime;

@Id
@Column(name = "file_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 2147483647)
public String getFileId() {
    return fileId;
}

public void setFileId(String fileId) {
    this.fileId = fileId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "refer_id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 2147483647)
public String getReferId() {
    return referId;
}

public void setReferId(String referId) {
    this.referId = referId;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "file_name", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 2147483647)
public String getFileName() {
    return fileName;
}

public void setFileName(String fileName) {
    this.fileName = fileName;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "file_type", nullable = true, insertable = true, updatable = true, length = 2147483647)
public String getFileType() {
    return fileType;
}

public void setFileType(String fileType) {
    this.fileType = fileType;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "file_data", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
public byte[] getFileData() {
    return fileData;
}

public void setFileData(byte[] fileData) {
    this.fileData = fileData;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "created_datatime", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = true)
public Time getCreatedDatatime() {
    return createdDatatime;
}

public void setCreatedDatatime(Time createdDatatime) {
    this.createdDatatime = createdDatatime;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    FileEntity that = (FileEntity) o;

    if (createdDatatime != null ? !createdDatatime.equals(that.createdDatatime) : that.createdDatatime != null)
        return false;
    if (!Arrays.equals(fileData, that.fileData)) return false;
    if (fileId != null ? !fileId.equals(that.fileId) : that.fileId != null) return false;
    if (fileName != null ? !fileName.equals(that.fileName) : that.fileName != null) return false;
    if (fileType != null ? !fileType.equals(that.fileType) : that.fileType != null) return false;
    if (referId != null ? !referId.equals(that.referId) : that.referId != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = fileId != null ? fileId.hashCode() : 0;
    result = 31 * result + (referId != null ? referId.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (fileName != null ? fileName.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (fileType != null ? fileType.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (fileData != null ? Arrays.hashCode(fileData) : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (createdDatatime != null ? createdDatatime.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "com.longz.ozssc.model.FileEntity[ fileId=" + fileId + " ]";
}

}
```

This is very popular entity class I used in our project. The entity primary key is fileId, there is a set of getter/setter pair to access this private attributes in the entity such as setFileId(String fileId) and getFileId().

My remote interface is:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.longz.ozssc.remote;

import com.longz.ozssc.model.FileEntity;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

/**
 *
 * @author cidylong
*/
@Remote
public interface FileEntityFacadeRemote {

  void create(FileEntity fileEntity);

  void edit(FileEntity fileEntity);

  void remove(FileEntity fileEntity);

  FileEntity find(Object id);

  List<FileEntity> findAll();

  List<FileEntity> findRange(int[] range);

  int count();

}
```

My EJB implement is:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.longz.ozssc.ejb;

import com.longz.ozssc.model.FileEntity;
import com.longz.ozssc.remote.FileEntityFacadeRemote;
import com.longz.ozssc.remote.OzsscIdSequenceFacadeRemote;
import com.longz.ozssc.utils.datatime.DateTimeAssistant;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Remote;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author cidylong
 */
@Remote(FileEntityFacadeRemote.class)
@Stateless(mappedName="fileEntityFacadeEJB")
public class FileEntityFacade extends AbstractFacade<FileEntity> implements FileEntityFacadeRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "OzsscJPANBPU")
    private EntityManager em;

  @Override
  protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
}

  public FileEntityFacade() {
    super(FileEntity.class);
}

  @EJB
  private OzsscIdSequenceFacadeRemote ozsscIdSqFaRemote;

  @Override
  public List<FileEntity> findAll(){
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("FileEntity.findAllOrderByCreated");
    return new LinkedList<FileEntity>(query.getResultList());
    /*return super.findAll();*/
}

}
```

Every time when I call entity method getFileId(),

```
 String fileId = (FileEntity)fileEntity.getFileId();
```

supposed I will get a string return from entity something like:

```
**FILES20150200013**.
```

But my entity always return:

```
**com.longz.ozssc.model.FileEntity[ fileId= FILES20150200013 ]**
```

This return value is exactly other entity method toString()'s print out. Which means,

**when I call getFileId() method to access entity's primary key, the entity return a whole entity value to me instead of return a primary key.**

Is there anything wrong in my code or some bug in entity access method?

Any advise is welcome and with plenty appreciation.

EDIT:

When I tried to access the entity's primary key by using JPA 2.0 provided method:

```
Object identifier = 
                EntityManagerFactory.getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(fileEntity);
```

I got same wrong return. Annoy??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue by my self.

Actually. I test it with java client include WebLogic client lib and I found out, it is works fine in Java client.

And then, I put the same test code in Spring MVC context, not work. Spring MVC controller always give wrong return value. it is very funny.

As an alternative solution. I used Spring form object to re-organized the parameter by using ABN string instead of using FirmEntity, and then I pass the ABN string to EJB, I got correct return.

This is maybe can help someone else who met the same issue. I believe this issue caused by Spring Frameworks's AOP features who bindle wrong string to return value, should be very carefully when you using such features.